# Retrieve opening hours with holiday messages via Places API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I'm looking to show (within a site) the operating hours for a large number of global storefronts which are managed via Google MyBusiness/Places. When making an API request for a Google Place entry, it will return the opening hours as follows:

```
 "opening_hours" : {
     "open_now" : true,
     "periods" : [
        {
           "close" : {
              "day" : 0,
              "time" : "2200"
           },
           "open" : {
              "day" : 0,
              "time" : "0900"
           }
        },
        {
           "close" : {
              "day" : 1,
              "time" : "2200"
           },
           "open" : {
              "day" : 1,
              "time" : "0900"
           }
        },
        {
           "close" : {
              "day" : 2,
              "time" : "2200"
           },
           "open" : {
              "day" : 2,
              "time" : "0900"
           }
        },
        {
           "close" : {
              "day" : 3,
              "time" : "2200"
           },
           "open" : {
              "day" : 3,
              "time" : "0900"
           }
        },
        {
           "close" : {
              "day" : 4,
              "time" : "2200"
           },
           "open" : {
              "day" : 4,
              "time" : "0900"
           }
        },
        {
           "close" : {
              "day" : 5,
              "time" : "2200"
           },
           "open" : {
              "day" : 5,
              "time" : "0900"
           }
        },
        {
           "close" : {
              "day" : 6,
              "time" : "2200"
           },
           "open" : {
              "day" : 6,
              "time" : "0900"
           }
        }
     ],
     "weekday_text" : [
        "Monday: 9:00 AM – 10:00 PM",
        "Tuesday: 9:00 AM – 10:00 PM",
        "Wednesday: 9:00 AM – 10:00 PM",
        "Thursday: 9:00 AM – 10:00 PM",
        "Friday: 9:00 AM – 10:00 PM",
        "Saturday: 9:00 AM – 10:00 PM",
        "Sunday: 9:00 AM – 10:00 PM"
     ]
  },
```

But if you search for the same place via Google web search or Google Maps search, it will add hints if there is a local holiday which may affect the hours:

[image: opening hours with holiday hints]

Is there any way to access this information via the Places API that isn't obviously documented?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like its available thru API, unfortunately. I did find that business owners who uses Google Places can [update their business hours](http://googlesmb.blogspot.com/2010/10/google-places-and-tags-holiday-guide.html) for holidays. It just might only be available on their pages (Maps, Places) and not exposed in the API.